# Данная функция возвращает целое значение натурального логарифма при введенном x. Как сделать так, чтобы функция возвращала также и остаток?

Tags: c++, математика

```
double ln(double x)
{
    const double e = 2.7182818284;
    double exponent = 0;
    if (x < 0) x = -x;
    while (x > e)
    {
        x /= e;
        exponent++;
    }

    return exponent;

}
```

cmath использовать нельзя.

Comment: Или воспользоваться приближением — например, каким-то рядом.

Comment: После того как вы нашли целую часть возведите "остаток" от `x` в квадрат. Повторите процесс - получите половинки целого. Снова в квадрат, процесс - четверти. И так далее.

Comment: Закрывать вопрос не надо. Он классный.

Comment: попробовать можно магию : `Log[x] = Log [ x^2 ] / 2 ` Тогда уже будет с точностью 0.5 , потом 0.25 и т.д. *( x = 1 .. E )*

Comment: с помощью разложения а ряд Тейлора вычисляйте до нужной степени погрешности.  http://pasadvice.narod.ru/prog/ln.htm

Answer (score 2):

Вы использовали формулы логарифма `Log[x] = Log[x/e] + 1`. Можно дальше использовать формулу степенную `Log[x^2] = Log[x] * 2`. Нужно только задать аргумент точности.

```
static double lnn ( double x , int n ) {
  if ( n < 1 )
    return x - 1 ;
  const double e = 2.7182818284;
  double res =  0 ;
  while ( x >= e ) {
    res += 1 ;
    x /= e ; }
  return res + lnn ( x * x , n - 1 ) / 2 ;
}

double ln ( double x , int n = 18 ) {
  if ( x == 1 )
    return 0 ;
  if ( x < 1 )
    return - lnn ( 1 / x , n );
  // <= 0 => неопределёнка
  return lnn ( x , n );
}

# include <iostream>
int main(){
  std::cout<<"ln [ 1000 ] = "<<ln(1000)<<std::endl;
}
```